# how do i use the .one jquery function on this?

Tags: jquery

not sure what i'm doing wrong but it's not stopping after one click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".header").one('click', function(){
    $("#fourlocs").effect("scale", { percent: 152, direction: 'horizontal' }, 700);
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjMWJ/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) makes sure it only executes once *on each element you bind*, if you want one `click` events for **all** `.header` elements, you need to unbind them, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function headerShow() {
    $("#fourlocs").effect("scale", { percent: 152, direction: 'horizontal' }, 700);
    $(".header").unbind("click", headerShow);
  }
  $(".header").click(headerShow);
});
```

If it's the only `click` event on `.header` elements (and you're sure of this) you can simplify it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".header").click(function() {
    $("#fourlocs").effect("scale", { percent: 152, direction: 'horizontal' }, 700);
    $(".header").unbind("click");
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you - everyone else was right that the code was actually correct. except i didn't post that it was to be used multiple times. very impressed with this answer nick!

Comment: not sure how you can add to a question, but is there any way to add another transition to this?

Comment: $("#fourlocs").effect("scale", { percent: 152, direction: 'horizontal' }, 700); 
    $("#moreText").show(slow);   
 $(".header").unbind("click", headerShow);

Comment: @mrtunes - If you add a delay, yes, effects themselves (for some bizzare reason) aren't queued.

Comment: well in the case above adding #moreText.show will break the whole code EDIT - i guess cause "slow is not defined" hah

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to rewrite the code with what `.one()` should be doing.

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function(event) {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
  $(this).unbind(event);
});
```

Alternatively, check to make sure you're on jQuery version 1.1 or later.

Answer (score 0):

The `one` function will cause the event to fire at most once per element returned.  If you have multiple elements with the class `header` then the event will fire for each one you click on.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on jsbin.com using jquery 1.4.4 and jquery UI 1.8.0 - and it worked as it should. It only fired off once.

What versions are you using?